# AWS RDS Postgres - Is lower provisioned IOPS better than higher baseline IOPS? (5K P-IOPS vs 5TB gp2 storage)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, provisioned-iops

We have a Postgres running with a 5TB storage.
And we have provisioned 5K IOPS.
But, after reading the AWS documentation we found that storage with 5TB has more than 15K baseline IOPS. And also cheaper.

Now I'm confused.
Is lower provisioned IOPS better than higher baseline IOPS?